# WPF XAML Binding ApplicationCommands.Close does not work

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a rather simple binding and in my development environment it works perfectly but at the deployment machine it does not work. It is running from a network share.
The xaml is as follows :

```
<!--<ribbon:RibbonButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="2" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" SmallImageSource="Images/exit.png" />-->
<ribbon:RibbonButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="2" SmallImageSource="Images/exit.png" />
```

The xaml in comment does not work, so by removing the command binding the form loads otherwise i get a xaml parse exception:
Exception is: XamlParseException - 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '29' and line position '73'.
Of course you have to ignore the line number and the position here i just copy pasted the whole exception as it appears for me in here

I have no clue why this binding fails because it seems like a simple textbook binding to me.

Comment: Do you have the same .NET runtime on both machines? What happens on your machine if you build for Release mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to the problem via the trick described here :
http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/14/108728.aspx
The inner exception showed i was missing an assembly to some crystel reports assembly.
Pretty weird that this assembly dependency pops up in loading a component that has nothing to do with crystel reports nevertheless the inner exception clearly said could not load file or assembly SAPBusniessObjects.WPF.ViewShared. 
After installing the runtime environment of crystel reports, i do need crystel reports in another user control than this one, the problem dissappeared.

Good trick of Laurent, thanks man.